# How to use flex option -o (--output=FILE)

Tags: flex-lexer

I met a problem when trying to `flex abcd.l`. I wanted to redirect the output to a new file instead of the default one `lex.yy.c`
I looked up it in manual finding an option `-o(--output=FILE)` so I changed my command to `flex xx.l -o lex.yy.1.c` but error occurs.

```
flex: can't open --outfile=lex.yy.1.c
/usr/bin/m4:stdin:2621: ERROR: end of file in string
```

My working environment is `cygwin` and `windows 7`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put command line options *before* positional arguments:

```
flex -o lex.yy.1.c xx.l
```

Once a positional (filename) argument is recognized, flex assumes that all following arguments are also filenames. This is the normal form of argument processing for command-line utilities, although some (gcc, for example) allow options to follow the filenames.

(Personally, I'd suggest using a filename like `xx.lex.c`, but the principle is the same.)

Comment: For me, even `flex -o azure_lexer.lex.c azure_lexer.l` is giving error `C:\GnuWin32\bin\flex.exe: can't open azure_lexer.lex.c`

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB i'm getting exactly same error. Did you find any fix?

Comment: @Kiran Instead of using command line args for specifying file name, I now use `%option outfile="xx.lex.c"` from within the `.l` file. [here](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cr4bd/flex-manual/Options-for-Specifying-Filenames.html#:~:text=%25option%20outfile%3D%22FILE%22). Also, note that, command line arg is `--outfile="xx.lex.c"` and not `-o xx.lex.c`. (My bad, `-oxx.lex.c` is also allowed, with no spaces.)